# Delete all rows from a table not having a specific text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I delete all rows from a table which do not have a specific text in their column?
This does not work:

```
$('#mytable').find('tr:not(:has(th))').filter(
    function() {
          return $(this).find('td').text() != $("#some_component").val();
     }).remove();
}
```

**UPDATE**

The answers posted do not work for me. Either they remove all rows (I need to check for the text in a specific row not the first one-or any row for that matter) or they do nothing.
The following which is a modification of my first attempt works though

```
$('#mytable').find('tr:not(:has(th))').filter(
    function() { 

       return ($(this).find('td').text().indexOf($("#some_component").val()) < 0);
    } 
).remove();
```

Comment: specific column or any column?

Comment: @JeevanJose:Specific column (but this text is not expected to be in any other column anyway)

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Example One</td>
        <td>Example Two</td>
        <td>Example Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test One</td>
        <td>Test Two</td>
        <td>Test Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Trial One</td>
        <td>Trial Two</td>
        <td>Trial Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript jQuery (if it does contain):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myTable td:contains("Test")').parents("tr").remove();
});
```

JavaScript jQuery (if it does not contain):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myTable td').not(':contains("Test")').parents("tr").remove();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22QKM/

Comment: I want to remove if it does **not** contain the text

Comment: But why did you you a hardcoded string `"Test"`?My text is from another component.How can I put `$("#some_component").val()` in this `:contains`?

Comment: Replace Test with something like `' + $("#some_component").val() + '`

Comment: This code does not work if the table has more than one column.In my case it removes all rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code.

```
$("td:not(contains("+$("#some_component").val()+")"))
.siblings()
.filter(":not(contains("+$("#some_component").val()+"))")
.parent('tr')
.remove();
```

**Tested Code**

```
$('tr').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).find('td:contains("'+ $("#some_component").val() +'")').parent().css('background-color','red');
});
```

Test it and then replace `.css()` with `.remove()`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6vm/)**</kbd>

Comment: All the answers so far do **NOT** work for tables having more than 1 column.

Comment: @Jim sorry for give you solution without testing now see edit i have pasted tested code,

Comment: Hm.`#some_component` is part of `tr` in another table,

Comment: May be because your code does not specify a table, it is the reason it does not work?

Comment: @Jim may be...so add `#mytable` in `tr` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, the code you posted does work, as far as I can tell. Here is a jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btn").click(function () {

        console.log($("#some_component").val());
        $('#mytable').find('tr:not(:has(th))').filter(
            function() {
                  return $(this).find('td').text() != $("#some_component").val();
             }).remove();

    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EaNEd/

Comment: This will not work for more than 1 col.Since it seems that if it does not find the text in the first col it removes the row.For me this code removes **all** rows

Answer (score 0):

**Delete all rows from a table that does not having a specific text string:**

```
 function RemoveFromTable(tblID, VALUE){         
    $("#"+tblID).find(":not(:contains('"+VALUE+"'))").hide();
 }
```

**Note:You can also use "remove()" method instead of "hide()" method"**

**Call the function as follows:**

```
RemoveFromTable('table ID','value')
```